# Laravel 4.2 install on windows

Tags: php, git, laravel, laravel-4

I want to install Laravel 4.2 installation some packages via Composer. However, I am getting an error

> “failed to clone  git@github.com:symphony/Translation.git.git was not found. Check that it is installed in your path env. ‘git’ is not recognized as an internal or external command”

I want to use version 4.2.0 which is an older version of laravel. I’m successful to download if I do not mention version number but not when I include version number.
I tried:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel   composer create-project laravel/laravel newapp 4.2 –prefer-dist
```

Or

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel   composer create-project laravel/laravel newapp –prefer-dist 4.2.0
```

Or

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel   composer create-project laravel/laravel newapp –prefer-dist 4.2.*
```

Or

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel   composer create-project laravel/laravel {{newapp}} 4.2.*  –prefer-dist *
```

All with same error...

What do I need to make it work? Do I need to install git but How? i have no idea thanks for your help.

Note:I have latest composer downloaded yesterday July 24

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use an old and not updated version of Laravel?

The first one is the correct way to install Laravel with composer/create-project.
Can you try to clone the laravel/laravel repository and to run `composer udpate`?

Comment: Hi Romain, i'm learning Laravel on site and teach on 4.2.0 version and ask us to use 4.2.0 material which include excercice files.  yes i did update, have latest version but not clone can you provide more details as I'm new.

Comment: `composer update` will only download dependencies and not update composer. If you want to learn Laravel you should try the official tutorial site: https://laracasts.com.

Learn with an old version is not a good idea.

Comment: i'm learning in Lynda.com which i'm extremelly satisfied. and good for beginners like me. I want to learn MVC to understand concept..will look at your suggestion though..if you have solution for ny issue i'll take it;) thks Romain

Comment: 0n Laravel site it says if you use download (instead of composer create-project ) requires git to be installed . Do you know how or where I can git download  ? seems error I'm getting is also related to Git... [link] (http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#install-laravel )

Comment: If you doesn't have git installed you need to download and installed it. You can do it by following instruction there: https://www.git-scm.com/

Answer (score 0):

Lynda was a good source of information for me to learn Laravel(4.2) and if I recall there was a course that went into detail on installing Laravel on Windows, I could be wrong but if you have Git installed already you will also need to add it as a variable in your Paths to be used in your prompts.

The link below should help you in setting the Paths to Git and they should be something along these lines.

`;"C:\path\git\bin";"C:\path\git\cmd"`

http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: thanks it worked after installing GIT which was not mentionned as at the time it was need for latest version

Comment: I'd recommend Laracasts over Lynda for learning Laravel. Jeffery knows his stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I bullishly downloaded and installed GIT not knowing option to choose (used command prompt option) as Romain suggested , reboot and retried and it worked.  Lynda indeed have a chapter on installation but did not mention Git so following instruction failed.  Note: only trying previous version failed, was ok for latest laravel 5 version before installation of Git.    Thank you all...one day lost of trying and testing  but happy ending :)